# Override "Deactivate the Device Admin App" Greyed Out,

Tags: android, apk, admin, unlock, mason

How would I override an android device to run the original Android OS when the option the "Deactivate the Device Admin App" is greyed out?  Legally any android device is capable of this.  I do not have access to a computer.  This is a "Mason" device. I know this is possible.

Factory Data Reset which brings me back to a "Mason" third party software activation screen.  The device is not under contract.

Comment: Your question doesn't deal with programming at all. We can't help on that. you should ask https://android.stackexchange.com/ instead